# Android app toolbar not hiding in scroll

Tags: android

Here is what I tried, the frame layout is fragment.. and that fragment displays a list on screen. when scrolling that list i want toolbar to hide... the code below is not working, what am i doing wrong. i am trying to follow tutorials

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
             <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:id="@+id/main_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
                 <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                       android:id="@+id/appbar"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="@color/purple2"
            android:minHeight="56dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"                 
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle" >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
        < /LinearLayout>       
       </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the indicator of what is the scroll to follow.

Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your ListView and everything should work.

*** EDIT ***

Upon further investigation I've discovered that basically the problem is the ListView. It doesn't implement `NestedScrollingChild` and hence the scrolling behaviour will not work.

The best you can do is transform that `ListView` into a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager` (which basically will look the same).

Other option is to add in Java code:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}`

but of course it will only work on Lollipop.

Comment: I also added it to my frame layout, as its the fragment where list is in.